# AWS SAM nested stacks

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-sam

I'm using nested stack with SAM, and I have a parent stack which contains SNS resource and two children, childStack1 want to publish a message to the SNS topic, childStack2 wants to get notified from the same SNS, but how can I access the shared SNS topic from childStack1/2 yaml or lambda?

`ParentStack:
├── ChildStack1

|-------NestedFunction1

│-------template.yaml

├── ChildStack2
|-------NestedFunction2
|-------template.yaml
template.yaml                <--this contains SNS resource`

Thx...